# How to remove single quotes around variables when doing mysql queries in Python?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I had a question pertaining to mysql as being used in Python. Basically I have a dropdown menu on a webpage using flask, that provides the parameters to change the mysql queries. Here is a code snippet of my problem.

```
select = request.form.get('option')
select_2 = request.form.get('option_2')
conn = mysql.connect()
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE %s = %s;"
cursor.execute(query, (select, select_2))
data = cursor.fetchall()
```

This returns no data from the query because there are single qoutes around the first variable, i.e.

```
Select * from tbl_user where 'user_name' = 'Adam'
```

versus

```
Select * from tbl_user where user_name = 'Adam'.
```

Could someone explain how to remove these single qoutes around the columns for me? When I hard code the columns I want to use, it gives me back my desired data but when I try to do it this way, it merely returns []. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a working solution dealing with pymysql, which is to ***rewrite the escape method in class 'pymysql.connections.Connection', which obviously adds "'" arround your string***. maybe you can try in a similar way, check this:

```
from pymysql.connections import Connection, converters


class MyConnect(Connection):
    def escape(self, obj, mapping=None):
        """Escape whatever value you pass to it.

        Non-standard, for internal use; do not use this in your applications.
        """
        if isinstance(obj, str):
            return self.escape_string(obj)  # by default, it is :return "'" + self.escape_string(obj) + "'"
        if isinstance(obj, (bytes, bytearray)):
            ret = self._quote_bytes(obj)
            if self._binary_prefix:
                ret = "_binary" + ret
            return ret
        return converters.escape_item(obj, self.charset, mapping=mapping)


config = {'host':'', 'user':'', ...}
conn = MyConnect(**config)
cur = conn.cursor()
```